# jQuery scrollTop not scrolling on iOS 12

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to scroll to a div with this code and it doesn't work on iOS 12, it works on all other versions up from 12 and on Android, web as well. What could be the problem.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('html').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#filtered-results").offset().top-400
    }, 1000)
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a bug on iOS 12.
For some reason `html.scrollTop` is always `0` on iOS 12 Safari.

**SOLUTION:** Use `window.scrollY` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
setTimeout(function(){
     $('body').animate({
         scrollTop: $("#filtered-results").offset().top-400
     }, 1000)
}, 100);
```

Comment: that one doesn't work on any mobile at all :/ I did try body and body,html and only when it's "html" works on mobile

Comment: Mobile devices should identify body; it doesn't identify html

Comment: I know, but it doesn't work :/ most people say that writing html,body will work on every device, but that doesn't work either